# SOCKS error using Selenium with Python 2.7x

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python 2.7x and I'm trying to interact with a website using Selenium. Every time my code reaches this aspect of my code, I get the below `SOCKS` error. I am using Firefox v37 and Selenium v2.45.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    get_password("www.facebook.com")
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in get_password
    driver.get(album)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 187, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpyuwka_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10132)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpyuwka_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpyuwka_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpyuwka_/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

def get_password(album):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(album)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")
    elem.send_keys(password)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    driver.quit()

get_password("www.facebook.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a *compatibility issue*, **upgrade selenium** to 2.45 (currently most recent):

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

And, just a quick additional note about the code: why don't instantiate and quit the driver instance outside of the loop - this can have a positive impact on performance:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for album in albums:
    for value in content_list:
        ...
driver.quit()
```

---

Update: you need to **provide a URL schema**, replace:

```
get_password("www.facebook.com")
```

with:

```
get_password("https://www.facebook.com")
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. I was running Firefox v31 following previous advice about Selenium errors but I'm now using v37 together with Selenium 2.45.0. I'm now getting a new error. Original post amended

Comment: Thanks @alexce. That works fine now and so I know there is no compatibility issue. I still get an error in my original code though. I think the error relates to "File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 43, in is_connectable
    socket_.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))". The code above works in isolation but the same code embeded in my main code doesn't work. I do query some URLs through tor during my code and so I do wonder if this causes problems. Having said that, tor browser is still running when I run above